# Determinant multiplication (det(ab)=det(a)det(b))

Tags: linear-algebra

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product

I found this proof (Proof 2).Could you tell me two things?

1: How do I know that if a matrix is invertible then it is a product of elementary matrices?

2: How do I see that if $A$ is not invertible then neither is $AB$?

Comment: For $1$, if you know that a matrix is invertible iff it's reduced form is the identity matrix $I$, then the operations you made to reduce $A$ to $I$ are represented by elementary matrices $E_i$ and you have $I=E_n\cdots E_2E_1A$, that is, $A=E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}\cdots E_n^{-1}I=E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}\cdots E_n^{-1}$ (each elementary matrix is invertible and the inverse of $E_i$ is also an elementary matrix). For $2$, suppose that $A$ is not invertible but $AB$ is. Then $(AB)C=I$ for a matrix $C$, and so $A(BC)=I$ and this suffices to conclude that $BC$ is the inverse of $A$, contradicting the hypothesis

Comment: Another proof for 2: let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the linear transformations associated with $A$ and $B$. By the rank-nullity theorem, if $T_1$ is not invertible then it is not surjective, so $T_1\circ T_2$ cannot be surjective; hence $T_1\circ T_2$ is not invertible.